# Edit to file renaming VBA to fix runtime error: file not found

Tags: excel, vba

Through some research and trial and error, I was able to come across this basic VBA that is helping me rename a large list of file attachments. I have been able to rename a few dozen attachments but I run into the run-time error '53: File Not Found.' Is there a way to modify the VBA to skip over the file names that cannot be found?

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Const strPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\FolderName\"
Dim r As Long
Dim n As Long
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To n
Name strPath & Cells(r, 1) As strPath & Cells(r, 2)
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Putting some error trapping into your code will be the first place to start.

Comment: @SkipIntro I'm a total VBA newb, what would something that look like?

Comment: You can first check to see if the filename is valid using the `Dir()` function. See my answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error handling is disabled with this statement:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

To enable error handling again you have to use this statement:

```
On Error Goto 0
```

It's good practice to disable error handling only for the statements where you realy want to skip the error. On the other side enabling and disabling the error handling may slow doen your code. In that case you can place it arount the loop.

```
On Error Resume Next
For r = 2 To n
  Name strPath & Cells(r, 1) As strPath & Cells(r, 2)
Next r
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the top of your subroutine:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

This statement does exactly what it says, it ignores the error and moves on to the next line of code.

You need to **use caution** when using this statement as it does not fix the error. For your current issue, it should be fine, but in many others you'll need to handle the error instead of ignoring it.

A good resource to get the basics is [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).

If you want to learn more about Excel VBA, brettdj's answer to [What is the best way to master VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524173/138938) is a great place to start.

To see how errors are affected by `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 0`, step through the following in your VBA Editor:

```
Sub ExcelVBAErrorDemo()

    Dim forceError As Integer

    ' ignore errors
    On Error Resume Next
    ' cause an error
    forceError = 1 / 0

    ' the error was ignored, and the integer variable will
    ' display its default value
    MsgBox "Our forceError variable = " & forceError

    ' turn default error handling behavior back on
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' now we'll get a run-time error
    forceError = 1 / 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for not only the help but the links to the learning material. VBA is something that I've been trying to self-teach just haven't had a chance to really get after

Answer (score 1):

Better than `On Error Resume Next` (in my opinion) is to check for specific/anticipated errors and handle them appropriately.  In this case, you can check to see if a filename is valid, and skip the `Name` assignment if it is not valid.

Check to see if it's a valid filename using `Dir()` function:

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Const strPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\FolderName\"
Dim sFile as String
Dim r As Long
Dim n As Long
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To n
    sFile = strPath & Cells(r,1)
    If Not Dir(sFile) = vbNullString Then 
        Name sFile As strPath & Cells(r, 2)
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: `strPath & Cells(r,1)` is calculated twice here; once stored in a variable already so use the result for the 2nd time too. Replace the critical line with:

`Name sFile As strPath & Cells(r, 2)`

Reduce redundancy!